# VBA Excel : Error showing alert (and stopping code) despite Error handling

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

i'm writing a code that filters out a table and selects the shown data to copy it elsewhere. If the filter I apply shows nothing in the table and my code tries to select "nothing", the error it normally would have generated should instead be redirected to "ErrorHandler2", and let the code carry on:

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler2 'Gestion des erreurs
 
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'get the desired column range which is declared in the cell
    startRange = "L2"
    endRange = "L23211"

    'select values from all filtered rows
    .Range(startRange & ":" & endRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy
    End With
```

Then  it proceeds to :

```
ErrorHandler2:
    
'Supprime filtre 
Workbooks("_DATA BASE Cr300.xlsx").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$23211").AutoFilter Field:=15
Workbooks("extract_Stats_TECHM_v2.xlsm").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("INTER").Activate
```

The Error isn't being redirected despite it showing up.
Does anyone know what might be stopping it from being detected ?

Seeing as i'm not a programmer by profession, I was hoping someone could help me out with what i'm sure is a simple problem.
Thank you !

Comment: Most likely another error has previously occurred (probably `ErrorHandler1` that you haven't shown) and you didn't deal with it properly with a `Resume` statement.

Comment: Please share the complete code (as text) from `Sub...` to `... End Sub` and a more detailed description of what you're trying to do. Mass-activating is surely not what you're after. Also, confirm if the code is located in `"extract_Stats_TECHM_v2.xlsm"`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'get the desired column range which is declared in the cell
        startRange = "L2"
        endRange = "L23211"
        Dim Rng As Range
        'select values from all filtered rows
        Set Rng = .Range(startRange & ":" & endRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If Rng Is Nothing Then
            'Supprime filtre
            Workbooks("_DATA BASE Cr300.xlsx").Activate
            ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$23211").AutoFilter Field:=15
            Workbooks("extract_Stats_TECHM_v2.xlsm").Activate
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("INTER").Activate
        Else
            Rng.Copy
        End If
    End With
```